# How can I toggle an extension action on Firefox using a keyboard hotkey?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox-extensions, hotkeys

Is there a way I can toggle actions on extensions using the keyboard, on Firefox? i.e. I'm looking for a way to map keyboard shortcuts to perform the same actions as when I click on extension buttons.

I'm *not* looking for a way to access extension/add-on settings. I just want the same action as when I click on the extension button using the mouse pointer.

Eg: I want to open the uBlockOrigins display, or, I want to log in to lastpass without leaving the tab I'm on currently.